# Repeated Record in php and mysql

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am trieng to list item form the database, however, the result comes out in two. 2 result is displayed for each record. currently i only have one record in the database but when i display them on the screen it is repaeted. i do not know why this is happening, i have tried to palce a counter and see how many times the loop goes on and the result is always once. however the result is displayed two times.

the code as follows:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">   
            <?php   
            if($bidCollection->selectBidsByStatusAndAppId(BidAccount::OPEN_NEW, $id)){          
                foreach($bidCollection->getBids() as $bid){
                $banker->find($bid->getCustomerId());   
                $counter=0;
            ?>


                         <div class='col-xs-12 bg-more-light-gray bidlist'>

                             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1">

                                <?php 

                                    if(!$uploader->findProfilePicture($banker->data()->_customer_id)){ 
                                         echo "<img src='image/holder.png ' width='50' height='50'  class='img-responsive' />";
                                            }else{
                                         echo "<img src='upload/proPicture/".$uploader->data()->pictureUrl."' width='50' height='50' class='img-responsive'/>";                         
                                    }
                                ?>              

                             </div>









                             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                <?php
                                    echo '<h2>Agent name :'.$validate->cleanInput($banker->data()->officer_name).'</h2>';
                                    echo '<h3>Institute name : '.$validate->cleanInput($banker->data()->bank_name).' '.++$counter.'</h3>';
                                    if($bid->getApplicationOwnerId() === $customer->data()->_customer_id){
                                                echo "<p>CheckBook: ";
                                                    if($bid->getRequestCheckBook()){echo "Yes";}else{echo "No";}
                                                echo "</p>";
                                                echo"<p> Minimum Deposit: AED ".$bid->getMinDeposit()."</p>";
                                                echo"<p> Direct Debit Card: ";
                                                        if($bid->getRequestCreditCard()){echo "Yes";}else{echo "No";}
                                                echo "</p>";
                                                echo"<p> Other Fees / Arrangement Fees: AED ".$bid->getFees(). "</p>";
                                                echo"<p> Account Will be ready in: ".$bid->getSetupTime() ."</p>";
                                    }
                                ?>          
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                <?php                   
                                $datetime = new DateTime($bid->getDatePosted());
                                $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
                                $time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
                                    echo '<h4> Date: '.$date.'<br/>Time: '.$time.'</h4>';
                                    echo"<form method='POST' action='viewBanker.php'>";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='banker' value='".$bid->getCustomerId()."'>";
                                    echo "<input type='submit' class ='btn btn-default' name='submit' value='View Profile'>";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                    echo'<br/>';

                                        if($bid->getApplicationOwnerId() === $customer->data()->_customer_id){                      

                                                echo"<form method='post' action='acceptAccountBid.php'>";                   
                                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$bid->getCustomerId()."' name ='bankerId'/>";
                                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$id."' name ='appid'/>";
                                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$bid->getApplicationOwnerId()."' name='ownerId'>";
                                                    echo "<input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Accept Offer' name='submit'>";

                                                echo"</form>";

                                        }

                            ?>                          
                             </div>
                        </div>

            <?php

                }
            }
            ?>
```

The Methods that returns the the values is as follows:

```
public function selectBidsByStatusAndAppId($status, $appid)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accountBid WHERE application_id = :appId AND status = :st";
        try {

            $sth = $this->_db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindValue(':appId', $appid);
            $sth->bindValue(':st', $status);
            $sth->execute();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->setAlert('danger', 'Information Presentation Error: ' . $e->getMessage());   
        }

        foreach ( $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $data) {
           $this->addBid($data);
        }

        return true;
    }



public function addBid($data = null)
    {
        $bid = new BidAccount($data);
        $this->bids[] = $bid; 

    }   


public function getBids()
    {
        return $this->bids;
    }
```

Comment: What does ```$bidCollection->getBids()``` return? Before the `foreach```, add ```echo "<p>getBids():<pre>".print_r($bidCollection->getBids(),true)."</pre></p>";``` and let us know what you get.

Comment: You might move the ```$bidCollection->getBids()``` outside the foreach, and put it's value in a variable so it's only called once.

Comment: The getBids() returns arrays of objects. all that it does is return a collection of Bid object and then using the foreach to extract each object and display their content.

Comment: That's pretty obvious from the code. But you're calling it every time you go through the foreach. Also, unless you echo it, how do you know for sure what it contains?

Comment: the print_r does not display anything, however the var_dump displays the record twice, but the Mysql has only one record. the same record is displayed on the screen and i don't understand what causing it to loop twice.

Comment: i did as you said  Sloan Thrasher . i put it inside a variable but the result it the same.

Comment: Any chance ```selectBidsByStatusAndAppId``` is being called more than once?

Comment: No. this function is only called once

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I want to thank my mates who tried to help me earlier. the problem was I had another function which I forgot to post it here bidExist()

```
public function bidExist( $appId , $id){


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accountBid WHERE application_id = :appId AND _customer_id = :id";
        try {

            $sth = $this->_db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindValue(':appId', $appId);
            $sth->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $sth->execute();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->setAlert('danger', 'Information Presentation Error: ' . $e->getMessage());   
        }

        foreach ( $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $data) {
           $this->addBid($data);
        }

        return $sth->rowCount();


    }
```

The function above looped through the collection to check and see if the object exists before this and if it is then you can not add anymore bid, however, i forgot to remove the addBid() function on this method and that cause the object to be added twice to the collection. This took me the whole night to figure out. but I thank everyone who tried to support and assist.